# How to set up cross-account AWS CodeArtifact access within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-vpc, aws-codeartifact

Here's my setup:

- using AWS Organizations to segregate different application stacks; each Organizational Unit has separate AWS accounts to separate Dev and Prod.
- one "Shared services" AWS account with a CodeArtifact repository containing private Python packages, including common packages for use by multiple OUs.

**This works**: I've been able to set up cross-org access to CodeArtifact and am able to pull down a package from CodeArtifact in `Account Shared Services` to say an EC2 instance in `Account A`.

I am setting up an AWS Glue job in `Account A`, and I want it to use some packages from my CodeArtifact repo.
**This works:** If I run the Glue job outside my VPC, no problem, I'm able to access CodeArtifact.

**This doesn't work:** However, I want to run Glue within my VPC in `Account A` (to access other resources running in the VPC).  It looks like when I do that, I lose the ability to connect to CodeArtifact.

This seems to be because when Glue runs within a VPC, AWS automatically creates an elastic network interface without any public IPs ([described in more detail here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-JDBC-VPC.html#connection-JDBC-VPC-ENI)).  AWS suggests using a NAT gateway to get around this.

Now, if my CodeArtifact repo were also within `Account A` (where my Glue job is), I think I could create a VPC endpoint for it that I could use to connect from Glue from within the VPC.  Is there some way to do something similar given its in a different account?  Everything I'm talking about here is all within AWS, I don't want to create a NAT gateway just to connect to an AWS service from another AWS service.

Answer (score 0):

Many AWS Services struggle with cross-account things. Drop AWS Support a ticket and they will tell you the details, it's the only guaranteed way of getting a correct answer on the topic as they often don't publish these kinds of nuances in any of the publicly available documentation.

Answer (score 0):

My question stemmed from an unclear understanding of the CodeArtifact service and VPC endpoints.
Specifically:  when a VPC endpoint is connected to an AWS service, it is simply a pathway for resources in a private subnet in the VPC to connect to the service without having access to the Internet.  The service itself is global and is not account-specific.

In other words, to solve for the scenario described in my question I was able to simply create a CodeArtifact VPC endpoint (I only needed the `repository` endpoint, not the `api` one) within `Account A`.  This gave the Glue job running within the `Account A` VPC access to the global CodeArtifact service, and so long as I had the necessary permissions set for cross-account access on the CodeArtifact domain owned by the `Account Shared Services` account, I was able to download packages for use in my Glue job.